# Code igniter controller view mysql

Tags: codeigniter, controller

I have one controller `abc_con` with view `abc_` view.

There is second controller `cart_con` with `cart_view`.

And I have third controller xyz_con with view **xyz_view.php**

The flow of my website is like when I click on `abc_view` then values go to `abc_con` and in `abc_con` there is function cartload(). This function load cart_view view. When cart_view submit all value go to `xyz_con` controller. In `xyz_con` there is `function loadxyz()`. This function load the `xyz_view`.

In `abc_view` there is an input with name pin code. This input value I can easy fetch in `abc_con`

I just wanted to transfer this `$data` t
Directly to xyz_view without storing in database.

Comment: provide some code fragments otherwise this entire question is absurd...

Comment: Use session data. [Sessions Documentation Here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend those controllers together
like this

1).in oneController.php

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
require APPPATH . '/controllers/twoController.php';
class oneController extends BaseController
{
    $this->abc();
}
```

2).in twoController.php

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
require APPPATH . '/controllers/threeController.php';//parent class is threeController now you can access to function abc using inheriting like this
class twoController extends threeController
{
    $this->abc();
}
}
```

3).in threeController.php

```
<?php if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class threeController extends CI_Controller
{
    function abc()
    {
        your code
    }
}//end of 3rd controller
```